# Read Inside Text File and Define Each Column as a New Variable

Tags: linux, bash, unix, centos, gawk

I have a text file that contains three columns of data.

I need bash to read inside the text file and then define each of the columns as it's own variable that be used farther down in the bash script.

I've been trying to use the following code but, it will only read the first line of the text file and then fail after:

```
while read line
do
site=`echo ${line} | gawk '{print $1}'`
lat=`echo ${line} | gawk '{print $2}'`
lon=`echo ${line} | gawk '{print $3}'`
done < /software/PLOT_SHARE/lamp_city_text
```

Text File Data:

```
KBOS 42.3629 -71.0064
LSC 44.5357 -72.0286
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it´ll help you. This way you´ll be able to do it !!

As you can see, the variable RES contains the commands that will create the bash variable when you execute the `eval "var=x"`. This way, the bash will recharge the variable value

Regards

**SCRIPT**

```
echo "BOS 42.3629 -71.0064" >> data
echo "LSC 44.5357 -72.0286" >> data
while read line
do
   var1=`eval echo $line | awk '{print "res="$1}'`
   eval `echo $var1 `
   echo "RES:"$res
   echo "VAR:"$var1
done < data
```

**RESULT**

```
RES:BOS
VAR:res=BOS
RES:LSC
VAR:res=LSC
```

Regards!!